# Tail Recursion and Iteration SML

Tags: iteration, translation, sml, translate, tail-recursion

This is my assignment.

(http://prnt.sc/aa3gwd)

I've been working on this one with a tutor and this is what we have come up with so far.

```
fun mult(a,b) =
  let
    val product = 0
  in
    if (a = 0) then 
      0
    else
      while a > 0 do
      (                  
        product := product + b;  
        if (a = 1) then 
          product
        else
          a:= a -1
      );       
  end;
; //the function did not run at end;, so we added these two semicolons below
;
```

Output of this is:

```
stdIn:102.11-103.6 Error: syntax error: deleting  SEMICOLON END SEMICOLON
```

I've only been introduced to SML in the last 2 weeks and I just can't get my head around it. Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: The exercise doesn't make a lot of sense to me -- what does it even mean for a non-recursive while-loop version to be in any sense "equivalent" to a tail-recursive approach? In any event -- `product := product + b` wouldn't make sense in SML since int variables are not mutable. Something like that would require an `int ref`. Have you studied those?

Answer (score 5):

You need two (mutable) reference variables; one for the product and one for the counter.

Something like this:

```
fun mult(a, b) =
  let val product = ref 0
      val counter = ref a
  in
      while !counter > 0 do (
          product := !product + b;
          counter := !counter - 1
      );
      !product
  end;
```

(This isn't exactly a translation of the recursive code you linked to, because that code was unnecessarily complicated. You may need to adjust, depending on your professor.)

(I would write the recursive version more like this:

```
fun mult (0, _) = 0
  | mult (_, 0) = 0
  | mult (a, b) = b + mult(a - 1, b);
```

It's unclear why the exercise has a special case for `a = 1`.)